# Deserializing JSON in C# with Known Object Names

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a json with known object names, but I am having difficulty trying to find a good example.

I can use:
`dynamic meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( json );`
which works, but I wanted to use:
`metadata meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<metadata>( json );`
but does not seem to be working.

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "topic": "Some Topic",
    "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    "deprecated": false
  },
  "notification": {
    "notificationId": "c829ec0b9b24",
    "eventDate": "2021-04-11T14:58:19.019Z",
    "publishDate": "2021-04-11T14:58:22.599Z",
    "publishAttemptCount": 1,
    "data": {
      "username": "UserName",
      "userId": "UserId",
      "eiasToken": "Token"
    }
  }
}
```

Classes

```cs
public class metadata
{
    public String topic { get; set; }

    public String schemaVersion { get; set; }

    public Boolean deprecated { get; set; }
}

public class notification
{
    public String notificationId { get; set; }

    public DateTime eventDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime publishDate { get; set; }

    public Int32 publishAttemptCount { get; set; }

    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public String username { get; set; }

    public String userId { get; set; }

    public String eiasToken { get; set; }
}
```

Page Load Event

```cs
String json;

using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( Request.InputStream ) )
{
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
                
metadata meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<metadata>( json );

//meta class is null and does not contain data
//Next line evaluates to NULL and does not work

String topic = meta.topic;
```

Comment: Try `public class Root { public metadata metadata { get; set; } public notification notification { get; set; } }`, and then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string represents an object with metadata and notification properties. So, you should make a root object like this:

```
public class RootObj
    {
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        public Notification notification { get; set; }
    }
```

And use like this:

```
RootObj myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>( json );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse only the metadata part then you can use the `JObect` for that:

```cs
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var metaRaw = semiParsedJson["metadata"];

if(metaRaw == null) return;
var meta = metaRaw.ToObject<metadata>();
```